# Azure AD B2C user tokens

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured the Refresh token lifetime to 90 days, but when the token returned by Azure AD B2C was always 24hrs only. Is there anything specific I need to do to extend the token lifetime?

Comment: Is it a single page app? Are you using MSAL.js 2.x?

Comment: How did you configure the Refresh token lifetime? In user flow?

Comment: I am using @azure/msal-browser:2.7.0. And I have configured the token lifetime in the user flow properties the following is the configuration https://www.screencast.com/t/Ze1ni6Mp

Comment: I have a single page app where user registers and interacts with our protected WebAPI. I also have an application that runs in the user system as a background application. This background application also should call our protected web API. For this, I need a long-lived refresh token. Can you suggest a way to get that token and store it in my background application?

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected scenario for PKCE flow

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas#security-implications-of-refresh-tokens-in-the-browser),

> The single-page applications using the authorization code flow with
> PKCE always have a refresh token lifetime of 24 hours.

Comment: Hi Dinakar, Thanks for the response. Refresh is token very much needed for my background application to work without user interaction. Do you know any other way to get the long-lived refresh token?

Comment: Hi @BhagavanReddy, You can use other code flows such as [auth-code-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) but with PKCE it is not possible.

Comment: Hello Dinakar, I am using auth code flow only but that includes PKCE by default. Can we use the Auth-Code flow without PKCE? Or can you suggest/provide any samples where the SPA application getting the long-lived refresh token

Comment: Hi @BhagavanReddy, `Auth code flow` and `Auth code flow with PKCE` are different. Yes you can use Auth code flow without pkce and it is designed for over all web applications and not SPA. Only two flows are available for SPA apps i.e., implicit flow and pkce flow.

Comment: For auth code flow with out pkce, please go through python sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/authorization-code-flow-sample/authorization_code_flow_sample.py).If you reequire spa alternative then please go through `implicit flow` sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2).

Comment: That is my main problem with the SPA app, the implicit flow doesn't give me a refresh token and with PKCE I will get a refresh token but not much useful. Trying different approaches to solving my problem. Anyway thanks for giving the clarificaiton.